# Can not connect to printer on one laptop

Tags: macos, printer, network-printer

So me and my wife have two laptops. Both of them are Macs. We also have a printer (Canon MG3600, though I really doubt this matters).

On one machine, we can print just fine. On the other, printing hangs indefinitely and displays "The printer is not responding". However, and here's where things get crazy, when viewing in CUPS, the printer appears just fine. Additionally, using the Printer's network diagnostic to print an IP address, pinging from one machine produces (as expected):

```
   64 bytes from xxx.xxx.x.x: icmp_seq=547 ttl=64 time=4.758 ms
   64 bytes from xxx.xxx.x.x: icmp_seq=548 ttl=64 time=4.361 ms
```

While on the other computer

```
   Request timeout for icmp_seq 582
   ping: sendto: Host is down
```

.... which... That's crazy right? I could understand printing not working but a simple network ping should be fine shouldn't it? (And yes the wifi works just fine).

Comment: What are the IP addresses of both computers? Are firewalls disabled for both computers?

Comment: Can your two PCs ping each other?

Comment: Both laptops can ping each other. the IP addresses are 192.168.0.16 and .7 respectively

Comment: FWIW, the problem appears to have magically resolved itself. I am none the wiser as to *why or how*, but I can no longer reproduce the issue.